# How can I insert my own records in Spring Batch Job Repository?

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

I am looking at using Spring Batch to process some data from a PostgreSQL database, but I have a long-running query/analysis that generates the input data - it isn't just a SELECT statement.  Instead of having an ItemReader that has to use a PostgresPagingQueryProvider to step through the data (I may have millions of records and the PostgreSQL JDBC driver cursor implementation retrieves all data to the client) which would call this long-running query multiple times, I was wondering if there was a way to do something like the following:

1. Have a 'data prep' Step/Job that has an ItemReader which calls a database function, and this database function performs the long-running analysis, storing the results in a database table.  The return value from this database function is the number of records it wrote.
2. This number of records written and success/failure status is then 'somehow' recorded in the Job Repository as the number of records written (I don't need an ItemWriter to actually write anything, since the function called by the ItemReader wrote the results to a database table).
3. The next Step/Job is a standard Spring Batch setup, where the ItemReader queries data from this database table, makes decisions in the ItemProcessor, and stores the results with an ItemWriter.

I know that there are other ways to accomplish this without using Spring Batch, but since I will have a Job Repository to track the operation of the 'standard' Spring Batch processing, I was hoping that there would be a way to also maintain the status of this 'data prep' Step/Job in the Job Repository as well.

It looks like a StepExecutionListener or JobExecutionListener might be an option of intercepting the Step/Job execution to set these values for storing in the JobRepository, but I was wondering if there was some other approach to accomplish this (or if this is just a really bad idea).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not use cursor based reader instead of paging reader?

Comment: One of the items I mentioned above is that the PostgreSQL JDBC driver has a limitation that all data is retrieved and cached on the client - for processing millions of records, this is not acceptable: [link](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/81/callproc.html#callproc-resultset-refcursor)

Comment: I was a bit confused about that statement as server-side cursors are supported. Apparently not when [calling stored procedure](https://jdbc.postgresql.org/documentation/94/callproc.html). Thank you for the clarification.